# How to full join in MySQL with where clause and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (checkinout and leaves). The `checkinout` table store Attendance logs and the leaves table store leave logs. Those tables structure are the following:

`checkinout` table:

[checkinout table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6iDZ.png)

`leaves` table:

[leaves table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXTST.png)

Now, I want to gather All attendance logs and all leaves logs either `checkinout.CHECKTIME` row has data or not. So, I used the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM checkinout
LEFT JOIN leaves ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(checkinout.CHECKTIME, ' ', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(leaves.from, ' ', 1)
WHERE checkinout.PIN = 163 AND STR_TO_DATE(checkinout.CHECKTIME, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') between '2019-2-3 00:00:01' and '2019-2-4 23:59:59'
```

But the problem is when no data exists in `checkinout.CHECKTIME` row in specific date than the query does not return anything from `leaves` table, though `leaves` table has logs in specific date. After running the query below result has come:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P5eA.png)

So, How to solve the problem?
(I can't display the image, because I have not enough reputation)

Comment: Please add the tables in text format to your question.

Comment: You are supposed to add your information [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716), not as images (which is not the reason for why you cannot do it yet, but a good motivator). It is not really clear to me what your result should look like. Your result shows null for 2/4/2019, which seems consistent with not having an entry for 2/4/2019 in your second table. (As a general strong hint though: store your dates as type `datetime`, it will make your life much easier soon enough, e.g. when you want to look for ranges)